# Inject Maven settings.xml file into Kubernetes deployment

Tags: maven, azure, docker, kubernetes

This question is about running a Kubernetes deployment on Azure and we are completely new to Kubernetes. We have a new microservice called xde-deployer that we use to deploy projects onto other microservices. The xde-deployer builds projects using Maven and therefore needs a working Maven configuration. Normally this is provided in the user's `settings.xml`. In this case we are running it in a docker container, so xde-deployer will look for it in `/root/.m2/settings.xml`.

Normally when we deploy the docker container, we use a volume to pass the `settings.xml` which is located on the host. On Kubernetes of course this is not so straightforward. As the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059142/inject-code-files-directly-into-a-container-in-kubernetes-on-google-cloud-engine) state one could add the file later, or use a configMap. Both answers are a bit too vague for our purposes though. Is there really no way to do this from the deployment? I cannot imagine we are the only ones who need to pass Maven settings to jobs running on Kubernetes. How are others solving this problem? My main problem after reading the documentation is still: how do I get a file into the Kubernetes cluster at all when I am on Azure? Is there a kind of persistent volume or parameters store that can be easily shared by the pods?

Comment: If you want to dynamically mount files/secrets into a pod you will have to use config/secret maps (or some k8s outbound process which fetches those for you e.g., like hashicorp's consul-template - but thats even more complicated). I don't really get why this is a problem? You can regard your configmap as a drive which you mount into the pod - similar on how you do it in pure docker. In addition you can also use the k8s package manager [helm](https://helm.sh/) to further simplify that process - meaning you deploy configmap/pod resources in one command.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that we are very new to Kubernetes. The examples I found just showed a configMap used as a configuration file. Also I do not see how one would add a file in a certain location inside the pod such as the mentioned `/root/.m2` folder. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: Here is the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-specific-path-in-the-volume) about mounting ConfigMaps into pods.

Comment: Additionally for your consideration, one can always provide the explicit path to any settings file via `--global-settings` and/or `--settings` options to `mvn`; it is also possible to overwrite the `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` but I would find that solution opaque

Comment: Thank you, our main problem is: how do we get a file to the cluster to include it in the first place? We are running on Azure. See my clarification to the question above.

Comment: You can use [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/) for that. Also, I highly suggest you have a look into [helm](https://helm.sh/). If you got `kubectl` running in your pipeline processes, then including `helm` is a no-brainer.